# Floating point trap with C program using valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind, nan, floating-point-exceptions

I'm trying to figure out how I can find the exact position where my simulation code written in C generates NaNs.
I'm using plain C89 (but I can move to C99/C11) and gcc 4.4.5 on Debian squeeze.

Apparently there is a [patch](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=214950) for valgrind that should be able to perform this check.
Unfortunately it is not included in the binary distributed by Debian.
Indeed, trying to compile the vanilla valgrind plus the exp-floattrap doesn't work either (it seems not included in the final executable).

Have do you proceed to find the origin of these kind of bugs in C sources?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Old bugzilla items never die. Ish. The patch should now apply and work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll admit I don't use valgrind at all, just because I haven't needed it, but if all you're looking for is the case where a single variable is set to NaN, could you not just use GDB (or similar), and set up a watchpoint for the variable like:

```
watch var==NaN
```

This lets you know at what point that one variable becomes NaN, if that isn't the guilty operation itself, but a return value, you move yourself one function up the chain of guilt and set a watch point in that function, and so on and so forth, until you see the error.

I hope this helps a little :)